# Android if the given URL has cookies

Tags: java, android, cookies

I have the following code to read and split cookies

```
String[] x = Pattern.compile(";").split(CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("http://the.url.com"));
```

But I have a problem when the domain does not have cookies.

So I need to to something like this: If the given URL has cookies, split them else do nothing.

I have heard that there is something like `hasCookies()`, but I don't know how to use it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#hasCookies()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution for this

```
String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("http://the.url.com");

if(cookie != null){
    //do something
}
else{
    //do something else
}
```